# cant get row from sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

this is how I save sqlite data from non activity class using `getApplicationContext()`

```
public class SaveInSQLiteContacts {

    private Context context;

    public SaveInSQLiteContacts(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void save(String name, String imageKey, String email, String phone, String uid){

        SQLiteContacts sqLiteContacts = new SQLiteContacts(context);
        SQLiteDatabase database = sqLiteContacts.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        byte [] image = null;
        if(imageKey != null)
            image = Base64.decode(imageKey, Base64.DEFAULT);

        contentValues.put(SQLiteContacts.KEY_NAME, name);
        contentValues.put(SQLiteContacts.KEY_IMAGE, image);
        contentValues.put(SQLiteContacts.KEY_EMAIL, email);
        contentValues.put(SQLiteContacts.KEY_PHONE, phone);
        contentValues.put(SQLiteContacts.USERID, uid);
        database.insert(SQLiteContacts.CONTACTS, null, contentValues);

        sqLiteContacts.close();
    }
}
```

and this is how I`m trying to get data from it

```
private void checker(){
    SQLiteContacts sqLiteContacts = new SQLiteContacts(getApplicationContext());
    SQLiteDatabase database = sqLiteContacts.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.query(SQLiteContacts.CONTACTS, null, null, null, null, null, null);

    if(cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int i = cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteContacts.KEY_ID);
            int itemId = cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteContacts.KEY_NAME);
            int fixerId = cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteContacts.USERID);

            do {
                int id = cursor.getInt(i);
                String itemName = cursor.getString(itemId);
                String fixerUID = cursor.getString(fixerId);

                Log.d("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", itemName);
                Log.d("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", fixerUID);
                Log.d("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", String.valueOf(id));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    sqLite.close();
}
```

this is what I`m getting after:

```
Failed to read row 0, column 0 from a CursorWindow which has 0 rows, 6 columns.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the warnings in logcat.

Do you have something that looks like this one?:

> WARN CursorWindow Window is full: requested allocation x bytes, free
>   space x bytes, window size x bytes

This means that your cursor object is larger than the allocated size, which is normally 2Mb.

And the image you are saving might be the reason of exceeding this 2Mb limit.

Maybe you could query the other data and not the image and then load the image one by one.

If you only need the three columns that are in your code try the following:

```
String[] columns = new String[] { SQLiteContacts.KEY_ID, SQLiteContacts.KEY_NAME, SQLiteContacts.USERID };
Cursor cursor = database.query(SQLiteContacts.CONTACTS, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: but I`m not getting an imaage from this cursor request

Comment: columns - String: A list of which columns to return. Passing null will return all columns, which is discouraged to prevent reading data from storage that isn't going to be used.

Comment: In the columns parameter you send null, so it's returning all the columns, the image included, and that's why it exceedes the 2MB. If you don't need the picture just ask for the columns you need in that parameter.

Comment: Check the code I've just added to retrieve only specific columns and not the picture.

Answer (score 0):

Please check in Logcat by running below statement.May be cursor size is 0.  `Log.e("size",cursor.getCount());`

Comment: I`ve checked, it`s 1

Comment: Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
            KEY_NAME, KEY_PH_NO }, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);

Try like this.